# Why some names does not match any page in "Wikipedia" python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia, python-3.9

I am working on a project making a virtual assistant. while I am testing all the functions to make sure that no mistake and this is happening. When I said "Wikipedia" it will ask me "what topic you need to listen about" and I said "Rowan Atkinson" and it works, but when I ask for another name, for example like"Robert Downy Jr" it will appear an error like this"Wikipedia. exceptions.PageError: Page id "Robert Downey jr." does not match any pages. Try another id!" And I don't know why this happens so I copied the Wikipedia line and tested it in another file but it's still the same problem. I hope someone can't help me with this problem.
***Thank you very much for helping me!!!***

Here is my Wikipedia code

```
#import
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as we
import wikipedia


user = "Tom" #your name
assistant= "Jarvis" # Iron man Fan

Jarvis_mouth = pyttsx3.init()
Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("rate", 165)
voices = Jarvis_mouth.getProperty("voices")

# For Mail voice AKA Jarvis
Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

def Jarvis_brain(audio):
    robot = Jarvis_brain
    print("Jarvis: " + audio)
    Jarvis_mouth.say(audio)
    Jarvis_mouth.runAndWait()

#Jarvis speech 
#Jarvis_ear = listener
#Jarvis_brain = speak
#Jarvis_mouth = engine
#you = command

def inputCommand():
    # you = input() # For getting input from CLI
    Jarvis_ear = sr.Recognizer()
    you = ""
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as mic:
        print("Listening...")
        Jarvis_ear.pause_threshold = 1
        try:
            you = Jarvis_ear.recognize_google(Jarvis_ear.listen(mic, timeout=3), language="en-IN")
        except Exception as e:
            Jarvis_brain(" ")
        except:
            you = ""
        
        print("You: " + you)
       
    return you

def main():
    you = inputCommand().lower()
    if "wikipedia" in you:
        you = you.replace("wikipedia", "")
        Jarvis_brain("what topic you need to listen to")
        topic=inputCommand()
        results = wikipedia.summary(topic,sentences=3, auto_suggest=False, redirect=True)
        print(results)
        Jarvis_brain(results)
    else:
        print("I can't hear you, please try again")
main()
```

Here is the first terminal test:

```
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project> & C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/PC/Desktop/project/choice2.py
Listening...
You: Wikipedia
Jarvis: what topic you need to listen to
Listening...
You: Rowan Atkinson
Rowan Sebastian Atkinson  (born 6 January 1955) is an English actor, comedian, and writer. He is best known for his work on the sitcoms Blackadder (1983–1989) and Mr. Bean (1990–1995).
Jarvis: Rowan Sebastian Atkinson  (born 6 January 1955) is an English actor, comedian, and writer. He is best known for his work on the sitcoms Blackadder (1983–1989) and Mr. Bean (1990–1995).
```

And here is the second test:

```
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project> & C:/Users/PC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/PC/Desktop/project/choice2.py
Listening...
You: Wikipedia
Jarvis: what topic you need to listen to
Listening...
You: Robert Downey jr.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\choice2.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\choice2.py", line 54, in main
    results = wikipedia.summary(topic,sentences=3, auto_suggest=False, redirect=True)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
    return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 345, in __load
    raise PageError(self.title)
wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "Robert Downey jr." does not match any pages. Try another id!
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string said "Jr." instead of "jr.", it would work. You can set `auto_suggest` to `True` in the call to `wikipedia.summary` to avoid such errors.

Comment: But when I set auto_suggest to True the second test works but the first terminal test will error like this "Wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "roman atkinson" does not match any pages. Try another id!" and it also change the name "Rowan Atkinson" to "roman atkinson"

Comment: Hm, that's right, the api seems to be a bit limited. I would use a `try / catch` clause in this case. If the call with `auto_suggest` set to `False` throws, try again with it enabled.

Comment: the problem is gone and it working fine. Thank you so much for helping me to fix this problem I really appreciate your help. Wishing you a lot of health and success